# How to delete user in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Which of the following is correct method to delete the user account if `ouser` is bound to a specific user and `sclass` is user and `uname` represents the user to be deleted?

1. `ouser.DeleteUser`
2. `ouser.Delete uname`
3. `ouser.Delete sclass, uname`
4. `ouser.DeleteUser uname`

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Assuming you want to delete a local user you need to call the `Delete` method on an object representing the computer where you want to delete the user (use `.` for the local host).

```
computer = "."
username = "someuser"
GetObject("WinNT://" & computer).Delete "user", username
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Dim WshShell : Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.run "net user someuser /delete"
```